# Making flags and running default when none are given ARGV

Tags: ruby, flags, argv

I've been trying to figure out how to make flags using `ARGV` (I know about optparser, I don't want to use it)

What I would like to do is make a flag to load a file, and a flag to show the help, if no flag is given I want to run the program as it stands..

Example say_hi.rb:

```
def usage
  $stderr.puts("Usage: #{File.basename}: [-f|u] <file/path/>")
  exit
end

$file = nil
$help = usage

loop { case ARGV[0]
         when '-f' then  ARGV.shift; $file = ARGV.shift
         when '-h' then  ARGV.shift; $help = ARGV.shift
         else
           #No flag given, run program with "John" as the method argument

end }

def say_hi(name)
  puts "Hi #{name}! How are you?!"
end

say_hi("John")
```

Current output:

```
C:\Users\Jason\MyScripts>ruby say_hi.rb
Usage: say_hi.rb: [-f|u] <file/path/>

C:\Users\Jason\MyScripts>ruby say_hi.rb -f john.txt
Usage: say_hi.rb: [-f|u] <file/path/>

C:\Users\Jason\MyScripts>ruby sayhi.rb -h
Usage: say_hi.rb: [-f|u] <file/path/>
```

john.txt:

```
John
```

Expected output:

```
#running without flag =>
ruby say_hi.rb
#<= Hi John! How are you?!

#running with -h flag(help) =>
ruby say_hi -h
#<= Usage: say_hi: [-f|u] <file/path/>

#running with the -f flag(file) =>
ruby say_hi -f temp/name_file.txt
#<= Hi John! How are you?!
```

How can I accomplish doing this?

Comment: What is `say_hi.rb`?

Comment: @sawa Sorry for the confusion, edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: your code looks to me like it would work. what problem are you having? By the way, if you run `FOO=BAR irb` then in irb you can access `ENV["FOO"] # => "BAR"`. If you need to exit your program early, just use `exit`.

Comment: @maxpleaner Well for one when I run the program it doesn't do anything except show me the `usage` method. What I'm wanting is when no flag is given, it to run with "John" as the method argument to output `Hello John! How are you?!`

Comment: *`Hi John! How are you?!`

Comment: @JasonBorne see the answer by br3nt, but I might recommend taking a look at [thor](http://whatisthor.com/) if you want a little more struture for the CLI you're building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is exiting early because of this line: `$help = usage`.  The `usage` method has the command `exit` which causes the script to output the usage text and then exit.

Once you get past that, the `loop { ... }` will cause the program to run forever as it is an infinite loop.

What I think you want is something along the lines of this:

```
def usage
  $stderr.puts("Usage: #{File.basename(__FILE__)}: [-f|u] <file/path/>")
end

def say_hi(name)
  puts "Hi #{name}! How are you?!"
end

args = ARGV.dup
arg = args.shift # get the flag

case arg
when '-f'
  file = args.shift
  puts "doing something with #{file}"
when '-h'
  usage
else
  say_hi("John")
end
```

But if you're expecting the user to be able to parse in multiple args and flags and what not, then you can use a while loop to parse the args:

```
args = ARGV.dup
names = []

# parse all of the args
while (flag = args.shift)
  case flag
  when '-f'
    file = args.shift
  when '-h'
    # this will cause the program to exit if the help flag is found
    usage
    exit
  else
    # this isn't a flag, lets add it to the list of things to say hi to
    names << flag
  end
end

if names.empty?
  say_hi("John")
else
  names.each {|name| say_hi(name) }
end
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: How would I call the file to output the name within it? Could I do this with `IO.readlines("#{args}")`?

Comment: Look at the example for `readlines` in the [IO docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-readlines). You need to open the file first and it shows you how.

Comment: Then you could do `names.push(*names_from_file)` to join it with any names passed in via the command line or from multiple files.

Comment: Ah i missed that it was also a class method. Yeah it should work.